# "I found a script online but it doesn't work and I don't know why"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

How should we deal with this kind of question? I am talking about questions where the user has made a minimal effort to solve their problem - i.e. trying some code they found on the internet that they think might be relevant to their problem - but they show no evidence of *understanding* the code they have pasted into the question, and may even confess that they don't understand it.

Should such questions be closed?

Comment: At the very least, a few of them would fall under failing to *describe the specific problem*

Answer (score 14):

Sounds like a textbook case of:

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist